# Cannot Verify that the Backstage URL for Payment Service is Ever Called

Tags: php, sql, opencart

This is a bit of a workflow issue on an OpenCart payment extension I am working on.

I want to preface, I currently am hosting my server on a virtual machine at home - my domain for my OpenCart site is under `localhost:[somePortNumber]`.

I am implementing an e-commerce payment system called 99Bill (a Chinese payment service). I have done all the URL generation, send a GET request with all my correct keys and values to 99Bill, and I am currently on the step of post-transaction.

99Bill has a `key` in their URL which allows you to set a backstage URL. The backstage URL is essentially what gets called after a transaction, allowing the developer to do anything to the transaction information, such as updating their SQL database, sending an e-mail to the user, etc. Let's call this parameter `bgURL` (this is how 99Bill calls it anyways).

My `bgURL` is called `bill99_received.php`, and within it, I serve two functions:

1. Verify the identity of 99Bill using asymmetric encryption verification (more on this later)
2. If the above is true, update this session's order status (on OpenCart's back-end) from "Pending" to "Processed" using SQL queries.

Below is an example of how I retrieve the keys and values from the 99Bill callback. (NOTE: I am not entirely sure if this procedure even works, though in my staging server for a non-OpenCart extension, it works fine).

> ```
> $parameter_string=check_for_null($_REQUEST[merchantAcctId],'merchantAcctId');
> $parameter_string.=check_for_null($_REQUEST[version],'version');
> $parameter_string.=check_for_null($_REQUEST[language],'language');
> $parameter_string.=check_for_null($_REQUEST[signType],'signType');
> $parameter....... .. .
> ```

After I have all my keys and values, I decode and check it:

```
// Decode the signature message
$MAC = base64_decode($_REQUEST['signMsg']);

//Check if it is ok
$ok = $this->check($str, $MAC);
```

The `check(..,..)` function looks like this:

```
/**
 * Check whether the signed message sent back by the server is
 * correct or not.
 */
function check($str, $MAC)
{
    $fp = fopen(

        dirname(__FILE__) . '/path/to/mykey.cer',
        'r'
    );

    $cert = fread($fp, 8192);

    fclose($fp);

    $pubkeyid = openssl_get_publickey($cert);

    return openssl_verify($str, $MAC, $pubkeyid);
}
```

If everything is verified - good.

However, my issue is that, my script simply doesn't work. I don't know why.

My question is two-fold:

1. While this script worked under my staging server when it was *NOT* an OpenCart extension, right now, I cannot verify if 99Bill even calls this `bgURL`.
2. Would the fact that my `bill99_received.php`'s inaccessibility have to do with the fact that I am testing this under `localhost` and not a public-facing IP?
3. How do I verify that this script is called?

EDIT:

Looking deeper into the flow of the transaction, since my `bill99_received.php` is indeed only on my `localhost` machine, 99Bill will have no way to call it. My coworker suggested I use cURL, but I am quite not sure how I could generate some requests so it could be called through cURL.

EDIT 2:

Aside from `bgURL`, we have a `pageURL` as well, which is the customer facing page of what to execute after a successful transaction. This page would display a "Checkout was Successful!" This URL is also a `localhost` page, but it successfully gets displayed onto my browser.

EDIT 3:

Checking the Chinese API of 99Bill, I've found this line:

1. If `bgURL` is empty, 99Bill will GET the result to `pageURL`.
2. If `bgURL` is not empty, 99Bill will follow the instructions of `bgURL`.

Currently, my code is the second option - `bgURL` is not empty.

Comment: I think you answered your own question. Obviously the way it works require you to test it live. Im sure they have a way to generate a test transaction but the receiving page needs to be public for them to be able to post to it.

Comment: So you have any suggestions on using cURL to solve the issue? My coworker suggested that.

Comment: If you can't see from their API docs how format the reply then try logging what they send you and repeat that to your local script using curl. I would just put it online somewhere if I was trying to do this.

Comment: Do you mean put my received.php online? At the moment I do not have access to my staging server. If I put received.php online would I even be able to access my database?

Comment: yes it seems like that would be the easiest solution

Answer (score 0):

While I was unable to test this, I was able to cURL to my localhost URL and call `bill99_received.php` using the following command:

```
curl --data "key1=value1&key2=value2" "http://localhost:port/path/to/99bill_received.php"
```